# No sound card detected on Linux Mint 18.1 (& Windows 10) after dual-boot install on Asus UX410UQ laptop (Kabylake)

Tags: linux-mint, audio, dual-boot, live-usb

My soundcard is not detected on Linux Mint 18.1 (Kernel 4.4) after a fresh dual-boot install (only Dummy output in the sound control, and no soundcard detected in `alsa`).

It also seems that it has broken the sound on Windows (no soundcard detected).

**My setup :** Asus UX410UQ-GV044T with Intel Kabylake i7 processor, integrated 620 graphics + dedicated 940mx nvidia, 16Go RAM, 256Go SSD, 1To HDD, UEFI with secureboot disabled, CSM compatibility mode disabled.

**Where I think the problem comes from :**  Since the Linux install seems to have broken the audio for both Linux and Windows, and it is not a hardware issue (cf. below), it leads me to think that the GRUB bootloader has something to do with it ...

**What I already tried :**

- Restoring the hardrive to its initial state with Windows only => The soundcard is detected correctly after rebooting. This means that it is not a hardware problem.
- `sudo alsa force-reload` => Did not solve anything
- `lspci` does not show any audio device
- Installing `pavucontrol` => Did not solve anything
- Running the linux Mint live-usb after restoring the initial Windows install that works ==> The soundcard is now detected (in `alsa`, sound control center, pulse audio volume control, `lspci` ...) *but* no sound comes out of the speakers..

**What I will try next :**

- Try running live-usb with distributions that have more recent kernels (4.8 and above). I have read that it could solve some compatibility issues between recent hardware (e.g. [linux mint 18.1 audio problem](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/349079/linux-mint-18-1-audio-problem))
- If I find one that works, try and install it and see if the problem persists...

For the moment I am stuck with the Windows only configuration ...

**Edit :** 
I solved the issue by moving to Manjaro, with kernel 4.9. The live-usb worked, as well as the installed system with dual-boot.
It seems that it was a kernel issue AFAIK.

Comment: If `lspci` sometimes lists and sometimes doesn't list the sound card, either your BIOS or your ACPI does some really funny stuff. You don't need to look into ALSA, grub etc. if it doesn't appear in `lspci`. Please provide an `lspci` output with and without soundcard, and also compare `dmesg` after boot with and without soundcard. If you can't make sense of `dmesg`, put both variants in a pastebin and edit your question with a link.

Comment: I solved the issue by moving to Manjaro, with kernel 4.9. The live-usb worked, as well as the installed system with dual-boot.
It seems that it was a kernel issue AFAIK.

Comment: The solution you found would be best posted as an answer, and the fact that our worked recorded by accepting that answer, rather than editing the title.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I modified the title, and added an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue by moving to Manjaro, with kernel 4.9. The live-usb worked, as well as the installed system with dual-boot. It seems that it was a kernel issue AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

After installing linux mint 18.1 Cinnemon as a dual boot next to W10 pro
the sound card was not detected for both W10 & Linux. A w10 recovery didn't change anything.(it did not erase the linux partition:))
I solved my problem by going into the bios and restore settings -> factory settings. Hope that this will work for other people as well.

Dell inspiron 7000.

Fredo